# Solve the following equation algebraically for n. Show your working using factorial notation.?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

[image]

a) $\dfrac{n!}{(n-2)!} = n(n-1)$

so the expression equivalent to $$\dfrac{n(n-1)}{6} = 12 \implies n(n-1)=72$$
I think its obvious the required solution is $8 \cdot 9 =72$, so $n=9$

b) $8Pn = \dfrac{8!}{(8-n)!} = 6720$
$$(8-n)! = \frac{8!}{6720} = 6 = 3!$$

so $8-n =3 \iff n=5$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good. Your answers are correct! Nice work.

You could also algebraically solve for $n$ in $(a)$, though I agree the solution seems "obvious": $$n(n-1) = 72 \iff n^2 - n - 72 = 0 $$ $$\iff (n-9)(n+8) = 0 \iff n = 9, n=-8$$

But since we are talking about non negative integers $n$ in these equations (since we are evaluating expressions with factorials), we can "throw out" $\;n = -8\,$ as an option, and we are left with $\;n = 9.$

Comment: are you positive? I think I'am wrong for a? can you try it .. I want to compare solutions It would be much help.

Comment: are you positive ? mind showing your solution for question a I swear I'am wrong..

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that $a$ is correct: Just compute $(a)$ when $n = 9$ to confirm: $\dfrac{n!}{3!(n-2)!} = \dfrac{9\cdot 8}{3!} = \dfrac {72}{6} = 12$ as desired.

Comment: @user73122:your answer is exactly $\large {\text{True}}$

Comment: would you guys! take a look at my new equation I need help on I think I'am almost at the correct answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425581/calculate-the-number-of-ways-that-committee-of-3-students-which-has-at-least-1-g

Comment: @amWhy: another TU +1