# number of ways to select a committee of 3 students with at least 1 girl

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a class comprises eight girls and six boys. How many ways can a committee of three students of among 8 girls and 6 boys be formed if the committee must include at least one girl?

My solution:

Ways to form a committee with exactly $g$ girls:

$g = 1$: $\displaystyle\binom 8 1 \binom 6 2 = 120$

$g = 2$: $\displaystyle\binom 8 2 \binom 6 1 = 168$

$g = 3$: $\displaystyle\binom 8 3 = 56$

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: at least one = all combination - combination without girls

Comment: You need to tell us how many boys and girls there are in the sample set...

Answer (score 6):

I will assume from your work that there are $\bf 8$ **girls** AND $\bf 6$ **boys** (I will take your "9" in the second computation to be a typo), and you need to determine how many committees can be formed from those $14$ students that have **at least one girl** on the committee of three.

The "simpler approach" to this would be to take the **total** number of possible ways of selecting **any** committee of 3 students from among $ 8 + 6 = 14$ students, and then **subtract** from that total the number of committees/combinations that can be formed **without** girls. The result will give you the number of committees which then contain **at least one girl.**

$$\binom{14}{3} - \binom 63 = \text{total number of committees of 3 students with $\bf at\;least\; one\; girl$.}$$

---

Alternatively, you can add the results of your posted calculations, and arrive at the same number of valid combinations as you would using this approach. Both approaches give you a total of $344$ possible *valid* combinations.

Comment: so the answer is 8?

Comment: No recall that $\binom {14}{3} = 14\,C\,3 = \dfrac{14!}{11!\cdot 3!} = \dfrac{14\cdot 13\cdot 12}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1} = \;?\;$, and $\binom 63 = \dfrac{6!}{3!\cdot 3!} = 20$. In all you should have $\;364 - 20 = 344$

Comment: Yes I understand that...from my giving solution what would be the next step.... I think that's the way the teacher wants it.

Comment: Just **add** your totals up and see that you get = $344$! ;-)

Comment: do you get the same answer using your approach?

Comment: Do you understand that the two approaches give the **same answer**: $\bf 344\;$? That's what's nice about problems like this, there are usually more ways to "count" the same thing!

Comment: @amWhy: nice discussion ... +1

Comment: @amWhy: Again $|\text{girls}|>|\text{boys}|$!! Are you Feminist Amy!!??:D+

Comment: hahahaha! That's funny! I'm not militant, but I do support advocating for girls and women, and paving the way for more of them taking an interest in, and pursuing, math!

Answer (score -1):

girls              boys             product
8c1=8           6c2=15         120
8c2=28         6c1=6           168
8c3=56          6c0=1          +56
                                               344

Comment: Please add some words to give this some meaning.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).
In particular, you may find helpful that `$\binom{n}{k}$` gives $\binom{n}{k}$.